# How to configure datadog for Rails to avoid "The called method `initialize' is defined her" deprecation warning?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, datadog, ruby-2.7

I’m using Ruby 2.7, Rail 6.2 and data dog (ddtrace) gem v 0.54.1.  I have this config set up

```
# config/initializers/datadog-tracer.rb

Datadog.configure do |c|
  c.tracer enabled: APP_CONFIG[:datadog][Rails.env][:enabled] && !Rails.env.test?
  c.service = ‘myapp’
  c.env = APP_CONFIG[:datadog][Rails.env][:env]
  c.use :rails, log_injection: true
end
```

When I run rspec tests, I notice these deprecation warnings …

```
/Users/my.user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/ddtrace-0.54.1/lib/ddtrace/configuration/agent_settings_resolver.rb:84: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/Users/my.user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/ddtrace-0.54.1/lib/ddtrace/configuration/agent_settings_resolver.rb:32: warning: The called method `initialize' is defined here
```

I’m not clear what these refer to or if its anything I can control or configure but eager to fix them.

Comment: https://github.com/DataDog/dd-trace-rb/issues/1542